# Use 'project' function in {terra} raster package, treat NA as 0s

Tags: r, raster, terra, rasterstats

I'm trying to resample/project a high res raster, using a low res raster as a template

```
library("terra")

high_res <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(1, NA, NA, NA))

low_res <- rast(nrow = 1, ncol = 1)

new_rast <- project(high_res, low_res, method = "average")
```

This works fine, but the value in the cell of the new rast is '1' as it has taken the average of all non-NA cells from the high_res raster.

Instead, I want it to treat NA values as 0. The result should be 0.25, not 1.

The method to do this must be memory-safe as I will be doing this on very large rasters (think 5m resolution covering a whole country).

Is there a clever way of doing this please?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace `NA` values with `0s`

```
library("terra")

high_res <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(1, NA, NA, NA))

high_res[is.na(high_res)] <- 0

low_res <- rast(nrow = 1, ncol = 1)

new_rast <- project(high_res, low_res, method = "average")
```

Comment: I tried this but the third line crashed my session due to the size of the data (though it works fine with this small example).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Gerald T, you can replace the `NA`s with zero. Here I show two  approaches for that that are better (memory safe) than using the `[<-` replacement function.

```
library("terra")
high_res <- rast(ncol = 4, nrow = 2, vals = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
low_res <- rast(nrow = 1, ncol = 2)

high_zero <- subst(high_res, NA, 0)
# or 
# high_zero <- ifel(is.na(high_res), 0, high_res)

new_rast <- project(high_zero, low_res, method = "average")
```

Now to remove the zeros from cells that should be NA you would need to do

```
isna <- project(high_res, low_res, method = "average")
x <- mask(new_rast, isna)
```

Unless all values in high_res are positive such that if the sum is zero you know that all the contributing cells were NA. In that case you can do

```
x <- subst(new_rast, 0, NA)
```

(And with these example data, aggregate would be a more obvious method to use.)

```
new_rast <- aggregate(high_zero, 2, mean)
```

Comment: In the example "high_zero" will be stored in memory won't it? So if the file is larger than memory it'll crash?

Comment: I can't use aggregate as in my real life example the template does not have the same origin as the other file i.e. they do not align. So I feel project is a better choice?

Comment: Perhaps a follow up question, but once this is done I'll then have to turn all the 0s in my "result" back to NA I think?

Comment: large datasets are always stored on disk (in a temporary file, if need be). I expanded the answer to address removing the spurious zeros.